# How to Show different page URL instead of default home page URL

Tags: redirect

Show different page link instead of default home page link.

For example when customer visit on `xyz.com` it must be redirected to a different page like `xyz.com/test/test1`.

So, when customer visit on `xyz.com` it must be changed to `xyz.com/test/test1`.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean : `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /test/test1 [L]`

Comment: I want to change URL when the customer visits xyz.com. The xyz.com must be changed and redirect to xyz.com/test/test1.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an HTML Redirect. Copy your header.php and rename to header-redirect.php and include this code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=xyz.com/test/test1" />
```

Then create a page template called page-home.php and include this code:

```
<?php
 /*
  Template Name: Home
 */
 ?>

<?php get_header('redirect'); ?>

     <p>Please wait, you are being redirected</p>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Set your hompage template to "Home" and it'll redirect.

One drawback is that visitors might see the blank page temporarily.

Comment: is there any way to change url.com to url.com/test/test1

Comment: Yeah it's this bit "xyz.com/test/test1" - just change it to whatever URL you need.

Comment: You don't understand when customer visiting url.com it must be changed to url.com to url.com/test/test1.

Comment: I'm sorry Ritesh you're correct, I don't understand. That's exactly what this will do.